# Proving an Equality involving Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and I still can't come up with a solution. Could you please point me in a direction? Here's the problem.

```
Let A, B be two 2x2 matrices, A =  a b  . A and B belong to M2(C). A*B - B*A = A.
                                   c d

Prove that for every n >= 2:
                              A^n * B - B * A^n = n*A^n
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you misstate the problem or forget to include a hypothesis? This certainly isn't true as stated; for example, if $A$ is the identity matrix, then $A^n B - BA^n = 0 \neq nA^n$.

Comment: Updated the hypothesis

Comment: Hint: $A^n B = A^{n-1} (AB)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to prove this using strong induction.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this recursive relation:

$$C_{n} = A^n B - B A^n = A^{n-1} (AB - BA) + (A^{n-1} B - B A^{n-1}) A = A^n + C_{n-1} A$$

How should one now prove it?